# Need to extract the values from excel and want to store values into Hashmap

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, data-structures, hashmap

Below is my requirement.

1. I want to read the values from excel
2. My excel has header and values as like below.

3.I am able to print all the values including header . But I want to store header as key and value as value in hash map and want to use those values (by calling that key) into my function.

Please someone help me to achieve this .I have attached my code. It is printing all the values line by line including heading.

```
Output: 
Studentname  
studentno  
Registration no  
john  
1234  
7654
```

if I call map.get(studentname) I need to get john respectively. Please someone help me :(

```
public static void ReadExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName, String Testcasename) throws IOException {

    String dataFile = resourceLocation + pointerData.getProperty("ENVIRONMENT") + "\\" + fileName;

    File file = new File(dataFile);

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    try {
        // Read sheet inside the workbook by its name
        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sh = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

        int totalNoOfRows = sh.getLastRowNum() - sh.getFirstRowNum();
        Row headerrow = sh.getRow(0);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {

            Row row1 = sh.getRow(row);
            if ((row1.getCell(0).getStringCellValue()).equals(Testcasename)) {
                for (int col = 1; col < row1.getLastCellNum(); col++) {
                    map.put(headerrow.getCell(col).getStringCellValue(), row1.getCell(col).getStringCellValue());
                }

            }
            System.out.println(map);// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: and what isn't working?

Comment: my code is printing the values and header line by line. I want to know , Is header  stored in keys ? also values stored in values of hashmap ? ....Also I want to return this Hashmap as results to my Function. There I want to use those values (by calling that key).

Comment: can you post a formatted example of the input? `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put("1", "abc");
  map.put("2", "def");
  System.out.println(map);
  System.out.println(map.get("1"));` prints 2 lines . first line is`{1=abc, 2=def}` second line is`abc`

Comment: probably your key is your header name

Comment: Are you having only one set of data or wanna handle multiple?

Comment: Need to handle multiple